# How long does it takes to create Thread in Android

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, timing

I've been looking for answer to this question, yet no one addresses it specifically. 
How long does it really takes to start a thread, from it's creation till after it starts? 
Why I am looking for this? I'm wondering if i have two tasks let's say one takes 50ms, and other 40ms, is it viable to run them in two independents threads or thread creation will take too long and I shouldn't do that.
Of course I'm not looking exact time because it may vary but I'm not sure what even influences time of creation + start.

Comment: If you are concerned about the cost of _creating_ a thread, one option is to create one (or more) threads before you need them. Once created, you can use it to do work without the time penalty of thread construction.

Comment: Creation time is very small (and you can create threads before using them as @kaan says) and if device have enough resources the start time is also very close to be immediate.

Comment: Additionally, Android requires to create AsyncTask to prevent blocking UI, but how big impact will it make for user to wait 90ms in one thread and approximately 50ms in two to receive output? (for games it's a huge difference :) ), try creating and running a set of simple threads and log time between both new and start/end. The main reason to move some work to another thread would be when the computational complexity of that work would depend on input - i.e. calculated complexity of sorting increases for every new element in collection.

Comment: @itwasntme Well, firstly it was mostly scientific question + looking for specifics for my optimization knowledge. If you are really interested my question was in relation to live data feed from camera2, I have java heap oom problems and anyway it's good for me to pass new objects into new threads in order to get old stuff garbage collected. And of course the faster i get even little things done, the faster i can release my limited memory resources.